# SSRS Changing subscription name

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is there any way to change subscription name without changing report's name? I have like 30 subscriptions for single report and it's little bit hard to find correct subscription to edit.

I'm on Sql Server 2012 Standard.

Comment: Are you aware of this query? I use this for my multi subscription reports https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1846/how-to-easily-identify-a-scheduled-sql-server-reporting-services-report/

Comment: I am aware of this, but it doesn't solve my problem. I have multiple subscriptions, that only differs in parameters, and list of recipients. Sometimes I have to add someone new into recipient list, and I have to look through many reports until I find correct one.